# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}≤q$ converges absolutely.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was preparing some tasks for the learning group I am meeting today and found this one interesting, but I have no clue how to do it!
There's $0<q<1$ so that $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}≤q$ converges absolutely.
How would the prove look like and what do I need to pay attention to? Is it correct that I could use the Comparison test for this one?
Oh and yeah, $a_n$ is a series, as far a I can see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple application of the comparison test.

$\lvert a_{n} \rvert \leq q^{n}$

and $q$ being in $(0,1)$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}q^{n}$ converges. Hence

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert a_{n}\rvert$ converges.